# Is this sentence grammatically correct and readable?

Tags: grammar, that, prepositions

I came across a sentence puzzling me, can you tell me whether the use of "that of" parts is correct? why or why not.

"You have been working here for 10 years, do you really need me to tell you whether your behavior is ***that of bad*** or ***that of good***?"

Can I just say "...whether your behavior is bad or good"? Thank you in advance!

Comment: .....that bad or that good.

Comment: Yeah, okay, this is nonsense. Where did you come across this, uh, sentence?

Comment: One of my friend was fired for letting a top-secret slip. His boss told him so. If it doesn't make sense, how do you put it? Thank you!

Comment: Never mind the comma splice after "years," that of bad or that of good *what*? *Behavior*?  *People*?  *Employees*?  What?  That of bad *what*?  That of good *what*?

Comment: FYI, it's either "One of my friends" (plural) or "My friend", not "One of my friend". Something in this context may help us understand what this boss's statement is really trying to say. What had your friend said to his boss to elicit this response?

Comment: It is possible the boss was speaking metaphorically about the personified concepts called Bad and Good, similar to "align ourselves to good and not to evil".  However, without knowing the boss, I can't guess his intentions.

Comment: @Satomi Ricky I've come across it before. It's easy to understand, though it is somewhat idiomatic of course. It can be paraphrased as _... whether your behavior is characteristic of bad or characteristic of good_.

Comment: "… that of bad or that of good" will always be wrong unless special circumstances justify a deviation from the norm. In this case "bad or good" would be correct… and for no reason but common usage "… good or bad" would be be more usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase *that of* is incomplete without a noun, at least in common usage.  The *bad* and *good* are adjectives.  So yes,

> "...is bad or good"

is appropriate.  To keep the *of* (which you don't need), you could say something like

> "... that of a bad person or that of a good person"

but there no need.

Comment: Good-natured and trying to be helpful, hence the +1. Probably wrong, though. There's something hiding behind the "that-a-bad" that we're not quite catching ... deducing ... deciphering correctly.

Comment: @Ricky it's definitely possible... Although maybe just a muddled mind behind a simple statement. Capitalize the G and B and place them in Lord of the Rings and those words are doing much more work than I'm giving them credit for here (for instance).

Comment: For the record, I do think that Baum was infinitely more talented, not to mention life-affirming, than Tolkien.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the sentence is grammatically correct, I guess the person who wrote it was just trying to sound fancy. I would've used something like, "is that of good or bad nature" or just anything to add a little something to it so that it is not so hard to read. It is grammatically correct though.

Comment: I'd mark it wrong in an essay.